# Can a RelativeLayout be passed through onClick?

Tags: android, onclick, android-relativelayout, imagebutton

in trying to streamline my code for the UI for the game I'm developing, I found it very worth while to try passing a RelativeLayout through onClick() of an ImageButton.

I was wondering if this is possible because it seems to be force closing whenever the ImageButton is clicked? Is this a problem with my code in general, or is the actual mechanism of passing through the RelativeLayout impossible?

Thanks in Advanced,
Here is my code:

```
public class SecondaryMenu extends Activity {

    ImageButton scrambledbutton; //Button That checks click and performs animation for the scrambled carton.
    ImageButton breakfastburritobutton; //Button for animation for breakfast burrito carton.
    ImageButton eggsbenedictbutton; //Button for eggs benedict carton animation.
    ImageButton eggsontoastbutton; //Button for eggs on toast animation
    ImageButton eggsaladsandwichbutton; //Button for egg salad sandwich animation.
    ImageButton eastereggsbutton; //Button for easter eggs animation.
    ImageButton ostricheggsbutton; //Button for ostrich eggs animation.
    ImageButton quaileggsbutton; //Button for quail eggs animation.
    RelativeLayout animatedcarton; //RelativeLayout for animating

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.secondary_menu); //Sets the current layout to the Secondary_Menu layout


           //Does animation based on button press - SCRAMBLED
           scrambledbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.scrambledbutton); 
           scrambledbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {               

                    //Calls the animation for the carton, and passes it the view to animate.
                    cartonanimation(findViewById (R.id.scrambledcarton));
                }
           });

           //Does animation based on button press - BREAKFAST BURRITO
           breakfastburritobutton = (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.breakfastburritobutton);
           breakfastburritobutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //Calls animation and passes view to be animated.
                    cartonanimation(findViewById (R.id.breakfastburittocarton));                
                }
           });

    }

    //Animation that slides clicked carton off the screen
    private void cartonanimation(View tempview) {
        animatedcarton = (RelativeLayout) tempview;
        animatedcarton.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
        animatedcarton.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.secondarymenuanimation);
        AnimationDrawable viewAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) animatedcarton.getBackground();
        viewAnimation.start();
        viewAnimation.setOneShot(true);
    }
}
```

And my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="top">

<!-- Carton number 1 - Scrambled -->
<RelativeLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="320dp"
  android:layout_height="160dp" 
  android:gravity="top"
  android:id="@+id/scrambledcarton">
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/scrambledbutton" 
        android:background="@drawable/cartonbackground" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
    </ImageButton>
    <TextView 
        style="@style/cartondishstyle"
        android:text="@string/carton1"><!-- Change for each Carton -->
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        style="@style/cartoneggcountstyle" 
        android:text="18"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"><!-- Adjust for each Carton -->
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Carton number 2 - Breakfast Burrito -->
<RelativeLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="320dp"
  android:layout_height="160dp" 
  android:gravity="top"
  android:id="@+id/breakfastburittocarton">
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/breakfastburritobutton" 
        android:background="@drawable/cartonbackground" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
    </ImageButton>
    <TextView 
        style="@style/cartondishstyle"
        android:text="@string/carton2"><!-- Change for each Carton -->
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        style="@style/cartoneggcountstyle" 
        android:text="18"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"><!-- Adjust for each Carton -->
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the Log Cat

```
04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/anim/secondarymenuanimation.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f040000

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1697)

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7533)

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at com.example.eggRoll.SecondaryMenu.cartonanimation(SecondaryMenu.java:54)

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at com.example.eggRoll.SecondaryMenu.access$0(SecondaryMenu.java:51)

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at com.example.eggRoll.SecondaryMenu$1.onClick(SecondaryMenu.java:35)

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag set

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:783)

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)

04-02 00:27:24.725: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1674):     ... 16 more
```

Comment: Please add any logcat output that may be of further description to your original post. However, to address your question regarding if you're "able" to pass an RelativeLayout via onClick - yes, you can, you can pass pretty much any *View that extends from View. :-)

Comment: added, hope it helps out

Comment: Post the secondarymenuanimation file

Comment: Try to clean&rebuild the project incase it's just trying to work with an "old" R.java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to put `viewAnimation.setOneShot(true);` before `viewAnimation.start();` since it would effect how it is played.

Comment: tried that, it didn't have any effect that I Could see, it still force closed.